# Drag and drop 2 boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a blue and a red box. I would like to drag and drop them, so that they can be switched. For now, I can drag the left box and drop it in the right box. That works fine but I cannot drag the right box and drop it in the left box.

```js
// Drag and the drop the items
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#title-drag, #storename-drag');

for (let element of elements) {
  // Allow the drop 
  element.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  element.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
  }, false);

  element.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
    let data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    console.log(event.target.className);
    event.preventDefault();
    element.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  });
}
```

```css
#title {
  background: red;
}
#storename {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Title -->
  <div class="row">
    <div id="title-drag">
      <div class="col-md-3" draggable="true" id="title">
        <div class="mg-item-inner">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-container='body' title='Gibt den Seitentitel aus'>
              <span class="name">TITLE</span><i class="fas fa-arrows-alt"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-container='body' title="Linie Erweitern / Reduzieren">
              <i class="fas fa-swatchbook"></i></button>
          </div><!-- /btn-group -->
          <div class="input-group" role="group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">prefix <i class="fas fa-sort"></i></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">prefix</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">suffix</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">none</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /input-btn-group -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div><!-- /input-group --><span type="button" class="btn add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
        </div><!-- /mg-item-inner -->
      </div><!-- /mg-item -->
    </div>

    <!--STORE NANE  -->
    <div id="storename-drag">
      <div class="col-md-3" draggable="true" id="storename">
        <div class="mg-item-inner">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-container='body' title='Fügt den Storename hinzu'>
              <span class="name">STORENAME</span><i class="fas fa-arrows-alt"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Linie Erweitern / Reduzieren">
              <i class="fas fa-swatchbook"></i></button>
          </div><!-- /btn-group -->
          <div class="input-group" role="group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">prefix <i class="fas fa-sort"></i></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">prefix</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">suffix</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">none</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /input-btn-group -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div><!-- /input-group --><span type="button" class="btn add"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
        </div><!-- /mg-item-inner -->
      </div><!-- /mg-item -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lb8e0pz3/

Why can I drop the left box but not the right one?

Comment: I think it's because you are appending it on your first item. 
`let data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text"); element.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));`
Try appending it to either your parent element or calculating the index of the item before you want to append and append it there.

Comment: @nabais thanks for this info! Probably it is not the parent element itself, since it could be a parent parent element as well and that should be either `#title-drag` or `#storename-drag`. Any idea of how I could build that statement?

Answer (score 0):

It just because you do

```
element.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
```

which always add item as last children... So moved element will be always last - that's why if you move second item, it will still be displayed as second. From the pure code perspective, everything works.

Comment: Oh I see. So how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you could see if the target is the first element of the parent, and if so add:

```js
if (isFirstElement(event.target)) {   // implement function
  element.parentNode.prepend(document.getElementById(data+'-drag'));
} else {
  element.parentNode.appendChild(document.getElementById(data+'-drag'));
}
```

Comment: I have tried it this way: https://jsfiddle.net/ep5q4khd/ ... but as you see that doesn't work for me.